# gcloud sdk not installing -- can't find

Tags: gcloud

Installing Google Cloud SDK I get the response below:

Note - I checked, and `C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython`
does indeed lead to a python `2.7` that runs fine.

```
Output folder: C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
from googlecloudsdk.calliope import arg_parsers
from googlecloudsdk.core import log
from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
from googlecloudsdk.core import config
from googlecloudsdk.core.util import files as file_utils
import hashlib
_hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.
If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 8, in 
import bootstrapping
File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 15, in 
from googlecloudsdk.core import config
File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\config.py", line 27, in 
from googlecloudsdk.core.util import files as file_utils
File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\files.py", line 22, in 
import hashlib
File "C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\hashlib.py", line 138, in 
_hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
Failed to install.
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have gotten it working, but I'm not sure I understand what the problem was.  After looking around, I tried setting a CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable which pointed to my local Python 2.7 installation and unchecking the Python installation box in installation.  Then it installed fine.  I'm still not sure why this was required, and any info would still be appreciated.  Is there any problem with using this solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you had python installed previously and did not set the Environment Variables correctly maybe the installer does not find the path where it was installed and requested to create a manual Environment Variables with  name CLOUDSDK_PYTHON.

You can check if there is a PythonPath Environment Variables created.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like the Python executable is trying to import _hashlib from an older version of the Python C source that doesn't have the `openssl_md_meth_names` symbol, presumably from an older Python installation on your machine.  Google Cloud SDK attempts to set the Python environment variables to prevent this from happening, but something seems to have slipped through in this case.  To address this issue you can try:

1. Set the `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` environment variable to point to a working local installation and run the installer, unchecking the option to install Python.  This is perfectly acceptable, and, in fact, the Linux and MacOS versions always use an existing Python installation.  It's only bundled on Windows because Windows doesn't have Python preinstalled.
2. Removing any existing Python 2 installations on your machine and trying to run the installer with bundled Python selected.

Alternatively, you could upgrade your existing Python 2 installation to >=2.7.9 and try running the installer with bundled Python selected.  That way, even if the bundled Python executable is trying to use C source from a different installation, it will be a newer version in which `_hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names` is defined.  I wouldn't recommend this as it could lead to other unexpected behavior.

If you'd like, you can open a Google Cloud SDK bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0.

Comment: Thanks.  As it happens, I had to update my local Python installation for other reasons.  Then I had to reinstall the Google Cloud SDK and it seems to be working fine.